# How to mimic the resizable StatusBar in the Spotify iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

I've been struggling to figure out how Spotify creates the UI for when the app goes into offline mode. They make it seem like the `StatusBar` has resized, but in reality they're just putting a view below, and resizing all controllers throughout the app. I've tried subclassing `UINavigationController`, subclassing `UIWindow`, resizing the window, but nothing seems to work for every case.

The interesting thing about the Spotify app, is that their solution seems to still work when iOS' own `UIViewController` subclasses are presented modally (as seen in the image below, showing apple's `MFMailComposeViewController` - you can tell it's not a custom controller because of the UIBarButtonItems).

If anyone has any insight into how this is possible, that would be awesome.

[image: Spotify iOS app]

Answer (score 0):

it's a very dangerous thing to do. I've done in the past and I had nightmares. Below the code that works in iOS4 and supports orientation changes.

```
- (void) _adjustViewControllerforTicker {
    TickerView* vv = [ApplicationContext getTickerView];
    if ([PreferenceDataModel isFxTickerOn]&& self.navigationController.view.frame.origin.y==0) {

    CGRect tableRect = self.tableView.frame;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableRect.origin.x,tableRect.origin.y, tableRect.size.width, tableRect.size.height -20);
    UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
    CGRect gframe = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.view.frame, 0, 20);
    self.navigationController.view.frame = gframe;
    if (!vv) {
        vv = [[TickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 20)];

        [nav.view addSubview:vv];
        [vv release];
        self.tableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,20.0,0.0);
        [ApplicationContext setTickerView:vv];
    }

    if (![PreferenceDataModel isTickerOn]) {
        self.tableView.contentInset= UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        if (vv){
           [vv removeFromSuperview];
           vv=nil;
           [ApplicationContext setTickerView:nil];
    }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation          { 
    [self _adjustViewControllerforTicker];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self _adjustViewControllerforTicker];
  TickerView* vv = [ApplicationContext getTickerView];
  if ([vv count]) {
    [vv startAnimation];
  }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self _adjustViewControllerforTicker];
}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I'm curious if your "ticker" still sits atop everything when you present a modal viewController? I already tried what you're doing (resizing the NavigationController's view).

Comment: My ticker is added on the UINavigationController level, so it persists even when you switch UIViewControllers. You could adjust your modal uiViewController the same way, so you will have a desired effect.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the "nightmares"?